# Why the accuracy of my neural network is falling when epoch increases?

Tags: neural-networks, model, accuracy, lstm, keras

Here is my model :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(look_back, trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.3, epochs=100, batch_size=50, verbose=1)
```

and  [image: here] is what I get... I see that the accuracy is suddenly falling for some epochs and remains low until the end, while the validation accuracy is quite great.

What's wrong ? Is it under/over fitting (I guess no overfitting, otherwise validation score should be low) ? How can I prevent from such a thing *a priori* (i.e. by initializing a parameter or sth like this). Is reducing the number of epochs would be a solution ?

What is quite strange is that the accuracy first grows and reaches a very high value, and then suddenly falls, with no appearing reason...

Thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn)

Comment: Are you trying to perform classification or regression? You probably need an activation function as last layer.

Comment: @Tonca I am trying to do binary classification on time series. That's why I use binary-crossentropy

Comment: Then you should put a sigmoidal activation function after the dense layer. I think

Comment: @Tonca Could you please write the line corresponding ? I have pain to see precisely what you mean...

Comment: @JanKukacka I don't think. Here my performances are first growing and then fall very fast at 68th epoch (only on the training dataset)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because it appears that this is related to using a linear activation function in the final layer instead of softmax. That is, it's a *conceptual* problem related to neural networks for classification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the reason of the instability of your network is the missing activation function as last layer.

As you are preformin a binary classification you should add a sigmoidat activation function right after the fully-connected layer. You can doit like this:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

Comment: I test it and give you feedback :) . Do you think I should change my number of epochs ? Indeed, it's only from the 68th epoch that it falls dramatically

Comment: I put model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(look_back, trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(1), activation='sigmoid') and I've got add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'activation'
error for the last layer... Why ? Should I set return_sequences=True for second LSTM layer ?

Comment: I've corrected the answer, I made a typo earlier

Comment: So return_sequences no needed (Why ?) ?

Comment: No, you don't need any information about the hidden states.

Comment: But between the two LSTM layers, it seems it's necessary ?

Comment: You're right I'm sorry, it's necessary for the Dense layer as well.

Comment: That's okay, I don't have the problem anymore BUT get another problem. Please look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362676/how-to-interpret-that-my-model-gives-no-negative-class-prediction-on-test-set

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.

What worked for me is to **decrease the learning rate when epochs increase**.

What probably happens, that model arrives close to some local maximum and then jumps of it, since the learning rate is to high.

For example you can make a few epochs with high learning rate `optimizer = optimizers.SGD(0.02)`, than switch to `SGD(0.02)` and after that to `SGD(0.01)`.

The actual numbers might be different.